# dropdown menu KivyMD not opening

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

When I try to open my dropdown menu nothing happens here is the python code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.menu import MDDropdownMenu
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class app(MDApp):
    dropdown = ObjectProperty
    
    def print(self):
        print("pressed!")
    
    def on_start(self):
        self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu()

        self.dropdown.items.append({"viewclass":"MDMenuItem","text":"Option 1"})
    
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_file("main.kv")
    


app().run()
```

Here is the .kv file:

```
MDBoxLayout:
    orientation: "vertical"

    MDToolbar:
        title: "MDToolbar"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.dropdown.open()]]


    MDLabel:
        text: "Content"
        halign: "center"
```

I hope that someone whos knows what they are doing can help me because I need it.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you must provide a `caller` for the `MDDropdownMenu`, which is used to position the `MDDropdownMenu`. If you add an `id` for the `MDToolBar` in your kv:

```
MDToolbar:
    id: toolbar
    title: "MDToolbar"
    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: app.dropdown.open()]]
```

Then you can provide a `caller` like this:

```
    self.dropdown = MDDropdownMenu(caller=self.root.ids.toolbar.ids.left_actions)
```

Comment: does it work for you @John Anderson because its not working for me

Comment: [TWIMC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71510107/kivymd-update-mddropdownmenu-open-generates-an-error)